# Jackson deserialize fails with class containing a Map with specific types

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a class that extends HashMap<Locale,String>, and which is referenced in another class that is being serialized into JSON with Jackson (jackson-core 2.10.5).
The result of serialization is:

```
{"code":null,"translations":{"@class":"c...TranslationMap","nb_NO":"Minimum","en_US":"Minimum","nn_NO":"Minimum"}}
```

*(class package name censored)*

But when de-serializing an exception is thrown that I haven't been able to figure out, how to work around:

> Could not resolve type id 'c...TranslationMap' as a subtype of `c...TranslationMap<java.util.Locale,java.lang.String>`: Not a subtype

The strange part is that I couldn't replicate this issue while using JDK that's part of DCEVM, but as soon as I switched to customer JDK adopt-openjdk-11 I started running into this issue.
Considering this issue occurs on servers as well, I have to make this work with adopt-openjdk-11.

Any ideas?

*TranslationMap.java*

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public class TranslationMap extends HashMap<Locale, String> {
   ...
   // empty constructor
   // some additional methods
}
```

*Translation.java*

```
public class Translation {
    private String code;
    private TranslationMap translations;
    ...
    // empty constructor
    // get / set methods
}
```

Deserialize method:

```
private Object deserialize(String value, String className) {
    try {
        var classType = Class.forName(className);
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, classType);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'c...TranslationMap' as a subtype of `c...TranslationMap<java.util.Locale,java.lang.String>`: Not a subtype
 at [Source: (String)"{"code":null,"translations":{"@class":"c...TranslationMap","nb_NO":"Minimum","en_US":"Minimum","nn_NO":"Minimum"}}"; line: 1, column: 39] (through reference chain: c...Translation["translations"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1761)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext._throwNotASubtype(DatabindContext.java:280)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.resolveAndValidateSubType(DatabindContext.java:241)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:72)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:113)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:193)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the `Class.forName(className)` does not resolve to the same Class object that is referenced in object mapper type factory, but seems to create another Class object for the same class. That's why it considers the types equal.
Solution for me was to use class from type factory instead.

```
private Object deserialize(String value, String className) {
    try {
        var jackson = new ObjectMapper();
        var classType = jackson.getTypeFactory().findClass(className));
        return jackson.readValue(value, classType);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```